# Retrieving all 'Child' items using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to write a SQL query to generate a table containing all 'child' items for each 'parent' (in this case Element).

I have created a simplified instance of this problem below and setup a db-fiddle instance for sake of clarity.

Given the following dummy data:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Element`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Element` (
  `idElement` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Element_Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idElement`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Property`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Property` 
(
    `idProperty` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Property_Text` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `Property_Node_ID` INT NULL,
    `Element_idElement` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idProperty`),
    INDEX `fk_Property_Element1_idx` (`Element_idElement` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Property_Element1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Element_idElement`)
        REFERENCES `Element` (`idElement`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Property_2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Property_2` 
(
    `idProperty_2` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Property_2_Text` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `Property_Node_ID` INT NULL,
    `Element_idElement` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idProperty_2`),
    INDEX `fk_Property_2_Element_idx` (`Element_idElement` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Property_2_Element`
         FOREIGN KEY (`Element_idElement`)
         REFERENCES `Element` (`idElement`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `Element` (`idElement`, `Element_Name`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'element_1');
INSERT INTO `Element` (`idElement`, `Element_Name`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'element_2');

INSERT INTO `Property` (`idProperty`, `Property_Text`, `Property_Node_ID`, `Element_idElement`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'property_a', NULL, '1');
INSERT INTO `Property` (`idProperty`, `Property_Text`, `Property_Node_ID`, `Element_idElement`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'property_b', NULL, '1');                          
INSERT INTO `Property` (`idProperty`, `Property_Text`, `Property_Node_ID`, `Element_idElement`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'property_c', NULL, '2');                              
INSERT INTO `Property_2` (`idProperty_2`, `Property_2_Text`, `Property_Node_ID`, `Element_idElement`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'property_2_a', NULL, '1');
INSERT INTO `Property_2` (`idProperty_2`, `Property_2_Text`, `Property_Node_ID`, `Element_idElement`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'property_2_b', NULL, '2');
INSERT INTO `Property_2` (`idProperty_2`, `Property_2_Text`, `Property_Node_ID`, `Element_idElement`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'property_2_c', NULL, '2');
```

I would like to output the following where each unique combination of the element and its properties are displayed row-by-row.

They are ordered first by the element, then by the first property, and finally by the last property:

```
-------------------------------------
element   | property   | property_2
-------------------------------------
element_1 | property_a | property_2_a
element_1 | property_b | property_2_a
element_2 | property_c | property_2_b
element_2 | property_c | property_2_c
```

[image]

Please see the link to the db-fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/csqTVJFTtpodqPksQtyrbs/0. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you have the list of properties that you want in the results, you can use conditional aggregation.  Otherwise, you should google "dynamic pivot".

Comment: Why is idElement null in the Element table? Perhaps a typo since it should not even allow null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the problem - and the naming policy is confusing - but what part of it does the following fail to address?

```
SELECT e.Element_Name element
     , p.Property_text property
     , p2.Property_2_text property_2
  FROM Element e
  JOIN Property p
    ON p.Element_idElement = e.idElement
  JOIN Property_2 p2
    ON p2.Element_idElement = e.idElement
 ORDER
    BY element
     , property
     , property_2;
```